# Header is displayed when user scrolls up - misaligns if activated too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The header on my site disappears when a user scrolls down the page. If the user begins to scroll up the header is displayed again, even if they're halfway down the page. If the user starts to scroll downwards, the header disappears again.

The effect works pretty well. Here's a CodePen showing the markup, css and javascript:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpWXpj

From what I can see the only issue it has is if you scroll and and up really quickly. It's almost like the code can't react quick enough and the `detached` class is added when it's not needed. Which means in the demo you get the (lovely) red background even when you're at the top of the browser.

Can anyone help/suggest how the script could be amended to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take out the

```
if (!currentScroll) {
    header.removeClass('detached');
}
```

out of the `else` block so that the menu jump fix is applicable at all times and not only when the `else` condition is satisfied.

Check updated codepen: http://codepen.io/nashcheez/pen/KWKjjq

So your js code becomes:

```
/* ==========================================================================
   #SHOW/HIDE HEADER
   ========================================================================== */

$(function() {

  var previousScroll = 0, // previous scroll position
    menuOffset = 70, // height of menu (once scroll passed it, menu is hidden)
    detachPoint = 220, // point of detach (after scroll passed it, menu is fixed)
    hideShowOffset = 5, // scrolling value after which triggers hide/show menu
    header = $('.page-head');

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (header.hasClass('expanded')) return;

    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop(),
      scrollDifference = Math.abs(currentScroll - previousScroll);

    // if scrolled past menu
    if (currentScroll > menuOffset) {
      // if scrolled past detach point add class to fix menu
      if (currentScroll > detachPoint) {
        var value = parseInt(header.css('transform').split(',')[5]);
        console.log(value);
        if (!header.hasClass('transitioning') && !header.hasClass('detached') && value != -110) {
          header.addClass('transitioning').one('transitionend', function() {
            console.log('transitionend');
            header.removeClass('transitioning');
            if (currentScroll > detachPoint) header.addClass('detached');
          });
        } else if (!header.hasClass('transitioning') && !header.hasClass('detached')) {
          header.addClass('detached');
        }
      }

      // if scrolling faster than hideShowOffset hide/show menu
      if (scrollDifference >= hideShowOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
          // scrolling down; hide menu
          if (!header.hasClass('invisible'))
            header.addClass('invisible');
        } else {
          // scrolling up; show menu
          if (header.hasClass('invisible'))
            header.removeClass('invisible');
        }
      }
    } 
    // only remove “detached” class if user is at the top of document (menu jump fix)
    if (!currentScroll) {
        header.removeClass('detached');
      }

    // If user is at the bottom of document show menu.
    if ($(window).height() + currentScroll == $(document).height()) {
      header.removeClass('invisible');
    }

    // Replace previous scroll position with new one.
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
  });
});

/* ==========================================================================
   #SHOW/HIDE NAVIGATION
   ========================================================================== */

/* 
 * Creates classes to enable responsive navigation.
 */

// Wait for the DOM to be ready (all elements printed on page regardless if 
// loaded or not).
$(function() {

  // Bind a click event to anything with the class "toggle-nav".
  $('.page-head__toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('show-nav')) {
      $('body').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('hide-nav');
      }, 500);

    } else {
      $('body').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
    }
    // Deactivate the default behavior of going to the next page on click.
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm it still seems to occur on the example I think. If you scroll down like 100px or so and back up. It displays the red header bar? Do you get that too? Thanks for the reply!